# Working as freelance from UK for a Japanese studio

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, japan

I would like to know what I would need to do in order to work legally as a freelance while I'm a UK resident but working for a Japan based company...

I'm living in London and I would receive regular work orders from a Japanese studio (probably in a weekly basis) They tend to hire an external agency within Japan for this kind of jobs until now. But if there is a possibility for me to do this remotely from here, from my house in UK, they will be happy to hire me.

There is something special that I would need to do to cover this matter, taking in consideration that the work is coming from Japan?. Where I would need to pay my taxes? If I'm living in UK and I'm doing the work from here I would need to pay the taxes just here even if the company is Japanese? There is something special that they have to do or is just a matter of pay my invoice as usual with other kinfolk UK based companies?

Sorry,I'm quite lost at the moment with all this andI'm not sure where to go to ask about all this matter.

Edit -

Yes I'm living in UK (I will go to Japan just a few days some months if is required but I'm based in London)

I worked before as freelance in UK (sone years ago) but at that point all my work request came from UK based companies. I paid my Self Assessment tax return per year and also the National Insurance as usual. At the moment  I'm working as an employee of a company in London, but this opportunity with a Japan based studio appeared and if is possible, I will leave my actual job and start to work remotely as a freelance for this Japanese company (and probably some others) from my workstation here in my personal Office in London.

So I was just wondering if is something different to do in this occasion, taking in consideration that the work request is coming from Japan. Or if I just need to operate as before, give them my budget per work request or week, and the proper invoice for it as usual and that's all? Keep the record of my invoices and tax income to pay later in the year and nothing more? There is nothing that involved any kind of double taxation UK/Japan in my case then?

Also they company from Japan doesn't need to do nothing special? Just receive my invoices and pay it as normal? Or they would need to declare the invoices in a different way because I'm based in UK instead of Japan?

Many thanks for the help and the link, Is also helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a tax resident in UK you pay tax in UK. For being a tax resident you should fulfill the following conditions.

Whether you’re UK resident usually depends on how many days you spend in the UK in the tax year (6 April to 5 April the following year).

**You’re automatically resident if either:**

- you spent 183 or more days in the UK in the tax year
- your only home was in the UK - you must have owned, rented or lived in it for at least 91 days in total - and you spent at least 30 days there in the tax year

[Check here on gov.uk if you need any more clarifications](https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence)